# Android Custom Adapter - Won't return view?

Tags: android, listview, fragment, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I'm having a problem with returning my view to a listview with my custom adapter. This is what I have in my main class which extends Fragment.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil_config, container, false);
    ListAdapter adapter = new PerfilOptionsAdapter(listOptions(), getActivity());
    listPerfilConfigOptions = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listEvents);
    listPerfilConfigOptions.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;

}
```

And here's what I have for my custom adapter named PerfilOptionsAdapter:

```
public class PerfilOptionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private List<PerfilConfigOption> options;
    private DateHelper dateHelper = new DateHelper();

    public PerfilOptionsAdapter(List<PerfilConfigOption> options, Activity activity) {
        this.options = options;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return options.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return options.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        PerfilConfigOption option = options.get(position);

        return option.getOptionID();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View line = inflater.inflate(R.layout.perfilconfigoptions_list , null);

        PerfilConfigOption option = options.get(position);

        TextView optionName = (TextView) line.findViewById(R.id.perfilConfigOptionName);
        optionName.setText(option.getOptionName());

        //ImageView photo = (ImageView) line.findViewById(R.id.perfilConfigOptionImage);

        //photo.setImageBitmap(option.getOptionImage());


        return line;
    }
}
```

Logcat response:

```
05-07 19:50:07.677    1730-1730/com.cupdev.voucomo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cupdev.voucomo, PID: 1730
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.cupdev.voucomo.Fragments.PerfilConfigFragment.onCreateView(PerfilConfigFragment.java:37)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm not sure why this adapter does not return any view at all? I've tried it with a SimpleAdapter with the same data and it works. I need to create a custom adapter to handle image data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong, on first glance your code looks good.  Any errors in the logs?

Comment: I'm edite the post, and add logcat response. Tanks for helping!

Comment: If you'll change this: listPerfilConfigOptions = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listEvents); to this: view.findViewById(R.id.listEvents); Does that helps?

Comment: @ruan65 good catch!  I was just looking at the adapter.  If `R.id.listEvents` in `fragment_perfil_config.xml`, the `findViewById()` would return null, ad then  `listPerfilConfigOptions.setAdapter()` would cause the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: I'm try this code, but, i don't have success. Look to my variables of debug panel ate this link: [link](http://s24.postimg.org/41um7q005/Debug_Mode.png) (i'd no reputation to post image =/), the adapter don't return the views.

Comment: Tanks for helping =D.

Comment: Do you still get the NullPointerException?  What is line 37 in PerfilConfigFragment.java?

Comment: in line 37 i have this code: `listPerfilConfigOptions.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: In what layout located this id: android:id="@+id/listEvents? Can you show? I think it should be here: fragment_perfil_config.xml

Comment: This was the bug , the correct would be: listPerfilConfigOptions , I just mistaking me in selecting the layout. Thank you for help! I solved the problem =D.

Comment: @ruan65 It's all working, tanks for all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are trying to find  listPerfilConfigOptions not where it is:

try this code:

`listPerfilConfigOptions = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listEvents);`

Comment: This is the variavles of my debug panel [link](http://postimg.org/image/41um7q001/)

Comment: Thank you all for helping me , the bug was simple thing , instead of having placed R.id.listPerfilConfigOptions I put R.id.listEvents.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me , the bug was simple thing , instead of having placed R.id.listPerfilConfigOptions I put R.id.listEvents.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil_config, container, false);
    ListAdapter adapter = new PerfilOptionsAdapter(listOptions(), getActivity());
listPerfilConfigOptions = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listEvents);
    listPerfilConfigOptions.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```